# Add Annotation text in content of TinyMce editor

Tags: tinymce-4, annotatorjs

I am using tinymce editor 4.3.8 version. I want to add annotation text(annotatorjs) to content of Tinymce editor content. i tried but not working.
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/

http://annotatorjs.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinymce itself having annotator plugin please refer the below link. https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-annotate/